# Is it possible to write a user-friendly panel scrollable without scrollbar (as in Android File Manager) in CSS?

Tags: css

Recently, I checked Android's File Manager built-in app on tablet and I liked the idea very much. It has a panel at the top:

```
 _______________________________________________________________________
|  Panel (scrollable without any scrollbar),  |   Fixed part: app icons |
|    contains your currently selected path    |     (it never moves)    |
-------------------------------------------------------------------------
                               CONTENT
```

And when a path to the file exceeds available width, you can easily scroll that left part, the tricky part is that there must never be any scrollbar in there.
And what's the desired behavior with the mouse? Just imagine this is a mouse cursor, instead of a finger, the visible effect must be the same: smooth, natural scrolling. I think that would be the ideal way.
Is there any demo of this kind of panel written in browser-based languages (HTML, CSS, maybe Javascript)?